Dividing Voronoi polygons into sectors
I have a point dataset and I'm trying to create Voronoi polygons and then divide the polygons into three sectors of 120 degrees.
I'm using QGIS so creating the Voronoi polygons is the easy part. I've tried using Geometry by expression to create the lines I want out to 1000m with the plan after that being to clip the lines to the polygon it is contained in but geom by expression isn't giving me the output I'm expecting.
See points and their Voronoi polys below.

The code for the geom by expression I tried is:
intersection(
$geometry,
collect_geometries(
    array_foreach(
        generate_series(0,360-120, 120),
        rotate(
            make_line(
                centroid($geometry),
                make_point(
                    x(centroid($geometry)), 
                    y(centroid($geometry))+1000
                    )
                ),
            @element,
            centroid($geometry)
            )
        )
    )
)

The out put of this is a line geometry layer with a filled attribute table but nothing being displayed on the map layer. Zoom to layer doesn't move the map and changing the symbology doesn't make anything appear so I'm not sure this has done what I had hoped.
Any suggestions on how I would go about making this work or possibly another way to generate three sectors per point in a Voronoi polygon?

One useful tip is to use Geometry generator as a Style on your polygon layer, and progressively expand the inner subsets of your formula to see what the editor shows as an output at each step.

Your expression works perfectly on my side. Have you checked you selected output geometry typeas Line in your Geometry by expression layer ?

Thanks for the replies. It turns out, much as you suggest, that I must have been forgetting to pick the line type in the geometry output. That was a lot of time trying to fix something that wasn't broken :)
